# Oracle query to get all rows with duplicate set of columns in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an oracle database table that has a set of columns that are duplicated 5 times. Like in the example below where columns (COL1_A to COL1_E) will exists 5 times in the same table except for the name of the column, the data type in each set of columns will be the same but in one set (COL1_A to COL1_E) does not have the same data type .

```
Cli_Id,Country,Name,COL1_A,COL1_B,COL1_C,COL1_D,COL1_E,COL2_A,COL2_B,COL2_C,COL2_D,COL2_E,COL3_A COL3_B,..
1      Test1   Lo1     1      2       3       4     5      1      2      3      4     5  
2      Test2   Lo2     5      6       7       8     9      5      3      3      4     5
3      Test3   Lo3     10     20      30      40   50      5      3      3      4     5
4      Test4   Lo4     11     22      32      42   52      53     3      3      4     5
5      Test5   Lo5     11     22      32      42   52      11     22      32      42   52
```

I need to write a query to retrieve all the rows which contain duplicates between the set of columns.

The result expected

```
Cli_Id,Country,Name,COL1_A,COL1_B,COL1_C,COL1_D,COL1_E,COL2_A,COL2_B,COL2_C,COL2_D,COL2_E,COL3_A COL3_B,..
1      Test1   Lo1     1      2       3       4     5      1      2      3      4     5  
5      Test5   Lo5     11     22      32      42   52      11     22      32      42   52
```

I have written one which has several unions but may affect performance as we have the intention to increase the set to 8. Thus looking for a simpler way to write this query.

Can you please advise on a simpler query keeping in mind it should be efficient and don't take too long time to run.

```
Select distinct CLi_id,Country,Name
from Table1
Where COL1_A = COL2_A
AND COL1_B = COL2_B
AND COL1_C = COL2_C
AND COL1_D = COL2_D
AND COL1_E = COL2_E
UNION
Select distinct CLi_id,Country,Name
from Table1
Where COL1_A = COL3_A
AND COL1_B = COL3_B
AND COL1_C = COL3_C
AND COL1_D = COL3_D
AND COL1_E = COL3_E
UNION
Select distinct CLi_id,Country,Name
from Table1
Where COL1_A = COL4_A
AND COL1_B = COL4_B
AND COL1_C = COL4_C
AND COL1_D = COL4_D
AND COL1_E = COL4_E
UNION
Select distinct CLi_id,Country,Name
from Table1
Where COL1_A = COL5_A
AND COL1_B = COL5_B
AND COL1_C = COL5_C
AND COL1_D = COL5_D
AND COL1_E = COL5_E
UNION
Select distinct CLi_id,Country,Name
from Table1
Where COL2_A = COL3_A
AND COL2_B = COL3_B
AND COL2_C = COL3_C
AND COL2_D = COL3_D
AND COL2_E = COL3_E
UNION
Select distinct CLi_id,Country,Name
from Table1
Where COL2_A = COL4_A
AND COL2_B = COL4_B
AND COL2_C = COL4_C
AND COL2_D = COL4_D
AND COL2_E = COL4_E
UNION
Select distinct CLi_id,Country,Name
from Table1
Where COL2_A = COL5_A
AND COL2_B = COL5_B
AND COL2_C = COL5_C
AND COL2_D = COL5_D
AND COL2_E = COL5_E
UNION
Select distinct CLi_id,Country,Name
from Table1
Where COL3_A = COL4_A
AND COL3_B = COL4_B
AND COL3_C = COL4_C
AND COL3_D = COL4_D
AND COL3_E = COL4_E
UNION
Select distinct CLi_id,Country,Name
from Table1
Where COL3_A = COL5_A
AND COL3_B = COL5_B
AND COL3_C = COL5_C
AND COL3_D = COL5_D
AND COL3_E = COL5_E
UNION
Select distinct CLi_id,Country,Name
from Table1
Where COL4_A = COL5_A
AND COL4_B = COL5_B
AND COL4_C = COL5_C
AND COL4_D = COL5_D
AND COL4_E = COL5_E
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OR` and `IN` as follows:

```
Select distinct CLi_id,Country,Name
from Table1
Where (COL1_A, COL1_B, COL1_C, COL1_D, COL1_E) 
      IN ((COL2_A, COL2_B, COL2_C, COL2_D, COL2_E), 
          (COL3_A, COL3_B, COL3_C, COL3_D, COL3_E), 
          (COL4_A, COL4_B, COL4_C, COL4_D, COL4_E),
          (COL5_A, COL5_B, COL5_C, COL5_D, COL5_E))
OR (COL2_A, COL2_B, COL2_C, COL2_D, COL2_E) 
      IN ((COL3_A, COL3_B, COL3_C, COL3_D, COL3_E), 
          (COL4_A, COL4_B, COL4_C, COL4_D, COL4_E),
          (COL5_A, COL5_B, COL5_C, COL5_D, COL5_E))
OR (COL3_A, COL3_B, COL3_C, COL3_D, COL3_E) 
      IN ((COL4_A, COL4_B, COL4_C, COL4_D, COL4_E),
          (COL5_A, COL5_B, COL5_C, COL5_D, COL5_E))
OR (COL4_A, COL4_B, COL4_C, COL4_D, COL4_E) 
      IN ((COL5_A, COL5_B, COL5_C, COL5_D, COL5_E))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are comparing the column level values corresponding to the cross level of identifying the attributes, you can use `UNION ALL` in a optimistic way. No need of joining the columns as you mentioned in your query.

Below query will provide you row level attributes,

```
select Cli_Id,Country,Name, col_A, col_B, col_C, col_D, count(*) from 
(select Cli_Id,Country,Name,COL1_A as col_A,COL1_B as col_B,COL1_C as col_C,COL1_D as col_D,COL1_E as col_E from table
union all
select Cli_Id,Country,Name,COL2_A as col_A,COL2_B as col_B,COL2_C as col_C,COL2_D  as col_D,COL2_E as col_E from table
union all
select Cli_Id,Country,Name,COL3_A as col_A,COL3_B as col_B,COL3_C as col_C,COL3_D  as 
col_D,COL3_E as col_E from table
union all
select Cli_Id,Country,Name,COL4_A as col_A,COL4_B as col_B,COL4_C as col_C,COL4_D  as col_D,COL4_E as col_E from table
union all
select Cli_Id,Country,Name,COL5_A as col_A,COL5_B as col_B,COL5_C as col_C,COL5_D  as col_D,COL5_E as col_E from table)
group by Cli_Id,Country,Name, col_A, col_B, col_C, col_D having count(*) > 1;
```

Below query will provide you column level attributes,

```
select distinct t1.* from table t1
inner join 
(select Cli_Id,Country,Name, col_A, col_B, col_C, col_D, count(*) from 
(select Cli_Id,Country,Name,COL1_A as col_A,COL1_B as col_B,COL1_C as col_C,COL1_D as col_D,COL1_E as col_E from table
union all
select Cli_Id,Country,Name,COL2_A as col_A,COL2_B as col_B,COL2_C as col_C,COL2_D  as col_D,COL2_E as col_E from table
union all
select Cli_Id,Country,Name,COL3_A as col_A,COL3_B as col_B,COL3_C as col_C,COL3_D  as col_D,COL3_E as col_E from table
union all
select Cli_Id,Country,Name,COL4_A as col_A,COL4_B as col_B,COL4_C as col_C,COL4_D  as col_D,COL4_E as col_E from table
union all
select Cli_Id,Country,Name,COL5_A as col_A,COL5_B as col_B,COL5_C as col_C,COL5_D  as col_D,COL5_E as col_E from table
group by Cli_Id,Country,Name, col_A, col_B, col_C, col_D having count(*) > 1) t2
on (t1.Cli_Id = t2.Cli_Id);
```

Comment: I am sorry but not sure why I am getting error missing left parenthesis

Comment: Please try now. Edited the query

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot data, group by column and value, take this id for which min(count) equals number of sequences (in your example 3, change it to 5 for current data, and 8 in the future):

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f2b0ea755e77ee100dc0d62c471bc5b5)</sup>**

```
select * 
  from table1 
  where cli_id in (
    select cli_id from (
      select cli_id, col, val, count(1) cnt
        from table1 
        unpivot (val for col in 
          (COL1_A as 'a', COL1_B as 'b', COL1_C as 'c', COL1_D as 'd', COL1_E as 'e',
           COL2_A as 'a', COL2_B as 'b', COL2_C as 'c', COL2_D as 'd', COL2_E as 'e',
           COL3_A as 'a', COL3_B as 'b', COL3_C as 'c', COL3_D as 'd', COL3_E as 'e'))
        group by cli_id, col, val )
      group by cli_id
      having min(cnt) = 3)
```

---

**Edit:**

> I will consider one row to have duplicates when it has at least 2 sets
> of columns identical

So we have to join unpivoted data:

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c216a63df08200146f4b937dd7d46487)</sup>**

```
with u as (
  select cli_id, country, name, ltr, num, val
        from table1 
        unpivot (val for (num, ltr) in (
          COL1_A as (1, 'a'), COL1_b as (1, 'b'), COL1_c as (1, 'c'), 
          COL1_d as (1, 'd'), COL1_e as (1, 'e'),
          COL2_A as (2, 'a'), COL2_b as (2, 'b'), COL2_c as (2, 'c'), 
          COL2_d as (2, 'd'), COL2_e as (2, 'e'),
          COL3_A as (3, 'a'), COL3_b as (3, 'b'), COL3_c as (3, 'c'), 
          COL3_d as (3, 'd'), COL3_e as (3, 'e')
          )))
select distinct cli_id, country, name
  from u a join u b using (cli_id, country, name, ltr, val) 
  where a.num < b.num
  group by cli_id, country, name, a.num, b.num
  having count(1) = 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But no, it does not meet my requirement. I will consider one row to have duplicates  when it has at least 2 sets of columns identical